# Firebase realtime database web not sending data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this script linked to my web form however whenever i click submit it doesn't appear on my firebase database.

I have it setup to find the form element by id and assign it to a variable. It then assigns it to a json object before submitting it to firebase. The database is always blank upon submit and has nothing in it. I am using firebase hosting to host the html website.

The code is here: https://pastebin.com/LgVCgKvT

```
var database = firebase.database();
submit2.onclick = function writeUserData() {
  /*  firebase.post("/gearscout2018", json ) */
  firebase.storage.reference.push(json)
```

above is a portion of the submit code I have

Comment: have you checked the console? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @GerardCuadras I'm not getting anything on the logs...

Comment: You're using a *super old* version of the Firebase client SDK.  Use the new stuff instead.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried the new implementation and that didnt work either

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete, minimal code that uses the new SDK.  Please don't put code in an image.  It's far better to copy it into a code block so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: This is invalid syntax and makes no sense: `firebase.storage.reference.push(json)`. My best guess is that you're looking for `firebase.database().reference().push(json);`

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue involving the way you reference storage

```
var database = firebase.database();
submit2.onclick = function writeUserData() {
// Get a reference to the storage service using a function
var storage = firebase.storage().reference.push(json)
```

Also, keep in mind that  firebase.database() is asynchronous

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks! what do you think the problem is?

Comment: @EnanSrivastava instead of using firebase.storage, try using firebase.storage().